# What's the easiest way to make HTTParty return an object/class rather than a JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, httparty

Right now I call:

```
def child(parent_id, child_id, params = {})
  if @api_token
    self.class.get("/parents/#{parent_id}/children/#{child_id}", query: params,
                      :headers=>{"Authorization"=>"Token token=#{@api_token}"})
  else
    self.class.get("/parents/#{parent_id}/children/#{child_id}", query: params)
  end
end
```

It returns the JSON response directly from the API as a hash. Is there an easy way for me to standardize the response so that it parses the JSON and generates a class?

Example:

```
Original Response
--------
{'child' : { 'name' : 'John Doe', 'age' : 23 } }

Desired Response
--------
res.name # John Doe
res.age  # 23
res.class # APIClient::Child
```

Comment: I was thinking of maybe using hashie. But then, I saw your requirement of `res.class` to return the root node. Hashie might not be much help here. I'm guessing, maybe you could extend hashie's APIs to make it bend to your needs ?

Comment: @bsvin33t hashie may not be a bad idea. I don't really need .class, just thought it effectively illustrated the concept.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved via custom parser passed to request call (however I would strongly advise not to do it and leave it as it is now)

an example of parser you could pass is

```
class InstanceParser < HTTParty::Parser
  def parse
    #assuming you always have a json in format { 'one_key_mapping_to_model' => data }        
    body_as_json = JSON.parse(body) #string parsed to json        

    model_class_name = body_as_json.keys.first # == 'one_key_mapping'       
    model_class_data = body_as_json[model_class_name] # == data
    class_instance = model_class_name.camelize.constantize.new(model_class_data) # will create new instance of OneKeyMapping

    class_instance
  end
end
```

and then in your api call pass `self.class.get("/parents/#{parent_id}/children/#{child_id}", query: params, parser: InstanceParser)`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the hash to an initializer.

```
class APIClient::Child
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

  def initialize(hash = {})
    hash.each do |k,v|
      public_send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your API client you would map between responses and objects:

```
def child(parent_id, child_id, params = {})
  opts = { query: params }
  opts.merge!(:headers=>{"Authorization"=>"Token token=#{@api_token}"}) if @api_token
   begin 
    res = self.class.get("/parents/#{parent_id}/children/#{child_id}", opts)
    case response.code
      when 200
        APIClient::Child.new(res[:child])
      when 404
        # not found - raise some sort of error that the API client consumer 
        # can catch maybe?
      else
        # probably just log it since there is little we can do here.
    end      
   rescue HTTParty::Error
     # probaly just log it. Could be a connection error or something else.
   end
end
```

This is probably a lot less magical than what you have hoped for but what is the role of a API Client if not to map between HTTP requests and objects suitable for consumption. Most of the boooring boilerplate code here when it comes to passing tokens and handling errors can be farmed out parent classes or modules.

Comment: Note that if you don't really care about declaring and documenting the properties of the objects you create you can simply use an `OpenStruct` or let your `APIClient::Child` extend `OpenStruct`.